# how to set video preview size of AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: macos, avfoundation

Working on a camera application with AVFoundation on Mac OS X 10.7

i used [session setSessionPreset] to set resolution of video size, but it only effects output movie file, my application need switch different preview resolution from low to high, some cameras that i am using output high resolution by default, like 2048x1536, it's not suitable for preview.

how can i get to this?